# Unity Error "Member 'Vector3.right' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ive been looking into game devlopment lately and i wanna make a 3d movement system. i did so following this tutorial https://youtu.be/KVOiKz-ddwk at one point he adds forward.right = 0; and right.y = 0; to the move function, for him it works fine but i get the error "Assets\Scripts\Movement.cs(37,9): error CS0176: Member 'Vector3.right' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

Heres the full code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed = 2f;
    private float currentspeed = 0f;
    private float speedSmoothVelocity = 0f;
    private float speedSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    private float rotationSpeed = 0.1f;
    private float gravity = 3;

    private Transform mainCameraTransform = null;

    private CharacterController controller = null;
    private Animator animator = null;

    private void Start ()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        mainCameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
    }

    private void Update () 
    {
        Move();
    }

    private void Move ()
    {
        Vector2 movementInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

        Vector3 forward = mainCameraTransform.forward;
        Vector3 right = mainCameraTransform.right;

        forward.right = 0;
        right.y = 0;

        forward.Normalize();
        right.Normalize();

        Vector3 desiredMoveDirection = (forward * movementInput.y + right * movementInput.x).normalized;
        Vector3 gravityVector = Vector3.zero;
        
        if(!controller.isGrounded)
        {
            gravityVector.y -= gravity;
        }

        if(desiredMoveDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(desiredMoveDirection), rotationSpeed);
            
        }
        
        float targetSpeed = movementSpeed * movementInput.magnitude;
        currentspeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentspeed, targetSpeed, ref speedSmoothVelocity, speedSmoothTime);

        controller.Move(desiredMoveDirection * currentspeed * Time.deltaTime);

        controller.Move(gravityVector * Time.deltaTime);

    }


}
```

I am on version 2020.1.1f1 Personal of Unity

Comment: Where exactly in the video does he have `forward.right = 0;`? It would be helpful to pin it down so that we don't need to watch all the way through a nearly-17 minute video. (It really shouldn't work - `Vector3.right` *is* a static property.

Comment: When you wrote `forward.right = 0;`, I guess you want `forward.y = 0;` or `forward.z = 0;`.

Comment: Either you mean ```forward.z = 0``` or you mean ```forward = Vector3.right;```

Comment: *and thus did Jon Skeet come to grace us humble vector monkeys with his presence*
but yes, as he had explained, `forward.right` should not appear in the code anywhere, since your `Vector3 forward` doesn't actually contain any property named `right`. If it works in his code, that means either he managed to change the definition of `Vector3`, or the video is wrong! I believe you have misread the code in the video, as I don't think either of those previous cases is likely. Perhaps he wrote that line accidentally, then changed it later before running it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be
`foward.y = 0;` instead of `foward.right = 0;`. I also found where the tutorial had added the lines in, here is [the link](https://youtu.be/KVOiKz-ddwk?t=870).